# Prevent double click on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script and I'm facing issues with the mobile navigation script.
Everything is working fine only the submenu dropdown works on double click either in case of open or in case of close.

This opens the main menus and on click open, the sub-menus are well on a single click

```
 $('.mobile-trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.custom-menu-primary .hs-menu-wrapper').slideToggle(250);
  $('body').toggleClass('mobile-open');
  $('.child-trigger').removeClass('child-open');
  $('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideUp(250);
  return false;
});
```

This script is added to close the current open sub-menus, but due to this script, everything works on double click instead of a single click.

```
   $('.child-trigger').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings('.hs-item-has-children').find('.child-trigger').removeClass('child-open');
   $(this).parent().siblings('.hs-item-has-children').find('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideUp(250);
   $(this).next('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideToggle(250);
   $(this).next('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').children('.hs-item-has-children').find('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideUp(250);
   $(this).next('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').children('.hs-item-has-children').find('.child-trigger').removeClass('child-open');
   $(this).toggleClass('child-open');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide working SO Snippet to investigate HTML/JS/CSS structures and to reproduce this issue?

Comment: This issue only on mobile? do you use `:hover` pseudo class in css for `.child-trigger` ? do you have more click event handler for children elements?

Comment: yes only on mobile navigation